# how to create sticky add to card button in bottom page scroll using website shopify?

Tags: shopify

how to create sticky add to card button in bottom page scroll using website shopify [enter image description here][1]

image this like create add to card button in bottom page scroll using website shopify
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxJds.png

Answer (score 0):

CSS' `position: sticky` is likely what you're looking for.

[Source](https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46)